# Estilos do bootstrap nao carregam

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, twitter-bootstrap

Eu tenho um website e estou a utilizar o Bootstrap mas por alguma razão quando vou ao index.php tudo funciona como deve de ser, mas se for ao index.php/ (com a barra no fim) o codigo HTML carrega mas o resto nao, nada de css nem js nem nada.

[image: sem barra]

[image: com barra]

Comment: tente adicionar o endereço completo ao chamar o js ou css. Exemplo:  <link href="http:// 192.168.2.106/PAP/css/estilo.css" ... />

Comment: Você pode resolver isso com regras de re-escrita de URL no seu servidor HTTP (Apache ou NginX ou seja lá qual for que você esteja utilizando).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você deve estar usando um endereço relativo para o seu arquivo CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="arquivo.css">
```

Quando você faz isso, o navegador vai procurar o arquivo em diferentes endereços, dependendo da presença da barra ou não:

- Se a barra de endereço contiver `http://192.168.2.106/PAP/index.php`, o arquivo buscado será **`http://192.168.2.106/PAP/arquivo.css`**
- Se a barra de endereço contiver `http://192.168.2.106/PAP/index.php/`, o arquivo buscado será **`http://192.168.2.106/PAP/index.php/arquivo.css`**

Para evitar esse problema, você deve usar endereços que não sejam relativos:

**Colocando uma barra no início do caminho para o CSS**, é possível indicar que o mesmo é relativo à raiz:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/PAP/arquivo.css">
```

Dessa forma, o endereço buscado sempre será `http://192.168.2.106/PAP/arquivo.css`, observando-se o host usado na barra de endereço.

**Outra solução, seria colocar o endereço completo do CSS**. É uma boa opção no caso em que o CSS está em um servidor externo... caso contrário, você terá dificuldade durante o desenvolvimento do programa.

Se for fazer isso, considere colocar o endereço sem especificar o protocolo, de forma a usar o mesmo protocolo que estiver escrito na barra de endereço.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//meuservidor.com/PAP/arquivo.css">
```

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, muito esclarecedor

Comment: Achei esta resposta melhor que anterior, pois obtive o mesmo resultado sem ter que estar a chamar o php a cada ficheiro css e js que incluia, mais uma vez obrigado pela soluçao e pela explicação

Answer (score 1):

Eu tive o mesmo problema ao criar SEF URLs e foi resolvido colocando o endereço do servidor em todas as requisições de css e js, como o Leonardo disse em seu comentário.
tente usar :

```
<link href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];?>/PAP/css/estilo.css" ... />
```

Assim você não terá problemas com o código quando subir para produção.

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: nao sei, eu vi na consola a mensagem "Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html" e a solução que encontrei diz para modificar o .htaccess e adicionar "AddType text/css .css" ao ficheiro

Comment: agora so me falta aprender a criar esse ficheiro, visto que não há nenhum na root do site

Comment: Quando você adiciona a barra no fim do endereço o servidor o trata como um diretório, e procura por uma folha de estilo inexistente, por isso resolve ao adicionar o endereço completo.

Comment: Funcionou com o $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] :D

Comment: Já agora, eu tentei adicionar o .htaccess com o código mas não deu em nada....